# axios , login with api , handle token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, axios, access-token

I new in react, trying to get a job. Doing test task, where I need to make login and registration with api and axios .I started with login. What I have  done , that i'm getting access_token, update_token , and expire in timestamp. I have no idea what to  do with that token , how to store it , redirect to other page . I tried to google it , but it seems too complicated.  It would be great if you could give me any advice with my next steps. Also any tutorials or post.

here is my code:

```
 handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.append("username", this.state.userLogin.email)
    formdata.append("password", this.state.userLogin.email)
    axios
      .post(
        "http://dev.**************.com/auth/get-token",
        formdata,

        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
        },
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

this is my response:

```
data:
access_token:"k0T*************nhN0EM1552651327"
expire:1552658527
update_token:"iZ6XX70M*************Nie1552651327"
```

Comment: go through any example its best for you right now

Comment: try this one https://github.com/sabuhinazarov/user-management-react

Comment: i agree with him not only refer tutorials but also refer some codes you can find on google like @RaiTalhaRehman gave you in above comment. still don't get it then comment here

Comment: you can save this token in store of app, or just set cookie

Comment: @JigneshSanghani this link has complete code it will help him a lot

Comment: actually he asked about complete concept he need to follow any tutorial and just ask about his problems and related to concepts.

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehman can't find any login sample in your link

Comment: did you clone the repo and started ?

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehman Yes , I did . There is no login form  ))

Comment: yes it has not login but it is axios base user management ,

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

Comment: try this tutorial then

Comment: this link have redux (state management system ) its a plus point for learners

Answer (score 0):

You can set permanent header in axios global instance like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
// ...
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token;
```

You can change `Authorization` by any header you want. Each requests will contain this token .

If in one of your axios response, you catch a 401 status; you can try to update your `access_token` and set it again in the axios global instance. You can even redirect your user to the login page.

For the view login part: once you retrieve your token, you have to change your container / screen (I assume that). If you use `react-router` (or other router) you have to `push` to a new route. If you use redux, you can store a `authenticated` boolean in one of your reducer and do conditional rendering with it: block access to some route / component.